# Dynamic image zoom using jquery in php

Tags: php, jquery

I am using jQuery image zooming on dynamic image files.

I have two files

1. default.php

   ```
   <head>
   <script src='/../../../../js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js'></script>
   <script src='/../../../../js/jquery.elevatezoom.js'></script>
   </head>

   echo '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="smallImgList(\''.implode('---',$smallImg[$key]).'\', \''.implode('---',$mediumImg[$key]).'\')" onmouseover="change(\''.$result1[$key].'\')"><img src="'.$a.'"  height="40px" width="40px" id="'.$key.'" /></a>';

   <script>
   function change(s)
   {
    $('.main-image img').attr('src', s);
    $('.main-image img').attr('data-zoom-image', a);   
    $('.main-image img').attr('style','width:200px; height:200px;');
    $('.main-image img').attr('class','demo'); 
   }
   </script>
   <script>
    $(".demo").elevateZoom();
   </script>
   ```
2. default_images.php

   ```
   <div class="main-image">
    <img class="demo" src='http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51kCAZT4LML._SX38_SY50_CR,0,0,38,50_.jpg' style="width:200px; height:200px;"/>
   </idv>
   ```

It's working properly with static images, but when I make it dynamic, like above code is showing, the zoom function is working but it can zoom only one default image,

While I checked on console, the `data-zoom-image` attribute have dynamic url.
But zooming default image.

Here is the link. click [here](http://test.youshop.in.ua/component/virtuemart/B00ESBVDNA-detail.html?Itemid=0).

I can't have any solution. Help me if you have any idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Call `$(".demo").elevateZoom` at the end of change function

Comment: i also tried that. but it can stop the zoom effect on static also

Comment: any one have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Your function "change" have parameter "s" but no parameter "a", used in `$('.main-image img').attr('data-zoom-image', a);`. Check again and try to send/update this value. It seems your are overwriting the data-zoom-image data.